# SSIS Build the project and try again

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2017

I keeping getting the following error, after adding an annotation in one of my workflow, per below

> The package 'x.dtsx' has been modified since the last build. Build the project 
>   and try again.  (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

I tried to debug/recompile, close and open the project and I still keep getting the same issue.

Has any of you encountered this error message? Can you please share how you have resolve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Change Deployment Model

Since you are using SSIS 2017 try changing the deployment model to **Package deployment model** instead of **Project deployment model**.

> The project deployment model was introduced in SQL Server 2012 Integration Services (SSIS). With this deployment model, you were not able to deploy one or more packages without deploying the whole project. SQL Server 2016 Integration Services (SSIS) introduced the package deployment model, which lets you deploy one or more packages without deploying the whole project.

Microsoft has provided a very detailed article describing the differences between both deployment model. You can check it out:

- [Deploy Integration Services (SSIS) Projects and Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/deploy-integration-services-ssis-projects-and-packages?view=sql-server-2017)

**Similar issue**

- [SSIS error Failed to start project](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1a435937-aa4b-4e8b-b8d1-75349d9dfc31/ssis-error-failed-to-start-project?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

Answer (score 0):

try deleting the build file(inside the bin folder) and build it back.